# How can I solve "This page isn’t working" when upload image?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, image-uploading

When I upload a image with **1.05 MB**, there is no error.

But when I upload a image with **2.36 MB** and then I submit it, I'm getting the following error:

> This page isn’t working
>
> myshop.dev is currently unable to handle this request.
>
> HTTP ERROR 500

Whereas in php.ini, I had set it like this :

```
upload_max_filesize=10M
post_max_size=10M
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: switch debug to true

Comment: @Alex, Where I can to set it?

Comment: in your `env` file.

Comment: @Pandhi Bhaumik, In my env file, I had set it. This : `APP_DEBUG=true`

Comment: "This page isn’t working" usually occurs if there's a syntax error or unequal closing brackets, are you sure you don't have any such problem in code?

Comment: @Echoes, I upload image with 1.05 MB, no error

Comment: Look at my question. I had update it

Comment: If you recently changed php.ini make sure to restart apache. Also check the apache log (eg. /var/log/apache2/error.log on ubuntu) to see what the error is.

Comment: It seems that there is an error because resize image can not be saved in folder thumbs

Comment: If the problem occurs when resizing, the problem may be due to a lack of memory. Check your `memory_limit` (but better check application logs, any 500 errors should be logged).

Comment: @Anton, My memory_limit=128M. It seems the memory is still enough

Comment: share your resize_image method

Comment: @Sandeesh, I had update my question

Comment: From your code and based on your comments the issue is definitely with the memory limit and failing to resize the bigger image. Check here http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/configuration . Remove the try catch block in your resize function and try it again. Check if any exception occurs.

Comment: @Sandeesh, If I remove the try catch block, it's the same. But if I change memory limit to be 1024M, it works. Before I think memory limit = 128M is enough :)

Comment: @TrendingNews glad you solved it. You should test with images as big as 5MB if you're planning to allow those in the app to check how much memory they consume. You can run some profiling to figure out the actual memory usage for resizing the images.

Comment: @Sandeesh, Okay. Thanks a lot